# Invalid Operands to Binary Expression (Int and NSNumber *)

Tags: objective-c

I'm learning objective C from CodeSchool and there's one section of learning OOP which I don't understand why it won't work but seems so simple to fix.

The Code:

```
- (void) decreaseBatteryLife:(NSNumber *)decreaseBy
{
    self.batteryLife = @([self.batteryLife intValue] - decreaseBy);
}
```

The error which points to the minus symbol before decreaseBy:

```
^invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'NSNumber *')
```

Comment: Curious, if you knew how to deal with `batteryLife` properly, how do you not know how to deal with `decreaseBy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`decreaseBy`" is a NSNumber *object* while the other value is a "`int`".  There's a difference (the first is an Objective C object, the other is a raw C type).

You need to get the raw "`intValue`" of your "`decreaseBy`" number.

Something like this:

```
self.batteryLife = @([self.batteryLife intValue] - [decreaseBy intValue]);
```

Comment: That was exactly it Michael! Thanks so much.
Could you also quickly clarify if obj-c uses both of the follow formats for accessing methods:
[object method]
object.method

It just seems like I've encountered both in learning Obj-C.

Comment: @user3746809 What you have seen is `[object method]` and `object.property`. There is no such thing as `object.method`.